# Creating oracle database physical files from migrated DB

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I migrated a database from SQL Server to Oracle 11g and there doesn't seem to be any physical files created after migration.

The client requires that they receive a copy of the database so they can clone it wherever they need. How do I create the files from the existing database? I'm from SQL server so it's pretty easy to get the files with a few clicks. Are there any similar feature for oracle 11g? Any alternatives if there aren't?

Comment: @Mat I have a copy of the sql server in my PC and migrated it to oracle 11g which is also from my PC. We usually pass the "default" state of the database to the client so they can install it on both production and test servers easily (using an installer). I can't remotely access the server. Any suggestions? I'm thinking of doing a backup of the database and restore it in the remote oracle DB.

Answer (score 1):

You should use export/import. On your side do:

```
expdp system/systempawwdord SCHEMAS=YOURSCHEMA
```

This will produce a file. Take it manually to you customer using CD, DVD, Pendrive. On customer site do:

```
impdp system/systempassword SCHEMAS=YOURSCHEMA
```

If the customer is using a different Oracle version, this is not a problem. You probably need to manually re-create tablespaces before importing the DB and add to the `impdp` command:

```
REMAP_TABLESPACES=OLDTBS:NEWTBS
```

For testing you can also do it on your actual instance, export, drop schema and import.

Comment: @Ste Please provide more specific answers and links to these "techniques". I migrated from sql server using sql developer's migration feature.

Comment: @Bahamut reading also your comments to your question this is my solution:

Comment: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php